# Show partial content of image using animation

Tags: ios, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I am working with images in iOS. So when a user presses let's say a button, I want an image to appear to fill up from the bottom to the top.

In order be more precise, imagine a thermometer that is empty and when you press a button the thermometer fills up from the bottom to the top. But I want this with animation.

Do you have any idea how to implement that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do it by having a second view acting as a **mask** over the image view with your image. Then you can apply simple **scale** transform and animate it revealing the image. Alternatively, you can animate the frame change. Effect will be the same. I'm attaching code for 2 ways of doind this.

Here is what I achieved in both cases:

[image]

Code I used for the case I:

```
@interface MyViewController ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIView *maskView;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"]];
    _imageView.center = self.view.center;
    _imageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0);

    [self.view addSubview:_imageView];

    _maskView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_imageView.frame];
    _maskView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _maskView.center = self.view.center;
    _maskView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0);

    [self.view addSubview:_maskView];
}

- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                     animations:^
    {
        _maskView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 0.0001);
    }];
}

@end
```

Code I used for the case II:

```
@interface MyViewController ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
@property(nonatomic, assign) CGFloat height;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"]];
    _imageView.center = self.view.center;
    _imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottom;

    _height = CGRectGetHeight(_imageView.bounds);

    CGRect frame = _imageView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 0.00001;
    frame.origin.y += _height;

    _imageView.frame = frame;
    _imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:_imageView];
}

- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                     animations:^
    {
        CGRect frame = _imageView.frame;
        frame.size.height = _height;
        frame.origin.y -= _height;

        _imageView.frame = frame;
    }];
}

@end
```

In both cases the end effect was the same.

Comment: Not how I would have done it, but +1 for animated gif!

Comment: That was good example. The best one is your second example! Now I created a button and each time I press it, my image increases. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing the frame of the view within the animate block.  For example, if myView was a 100x100 sized view:

```
myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, 0, 0);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                     animations:^
{
    myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, 100, 100);
}];
```

This example should enlarge a 100x100 view in the bottom left corner of the screen, making it appear to reveal itself from the bottom up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think is not that I am looking for because I need my view to be in each cell of a table view-like view. Thanks anyway!